# Почему не складываются значения ключей age?

Tags: javascript

```js
    const data = 
    [
      {name: "Саша", age: 19},
      {name: "Катя", age: 21},
      {name: "Миша", age: 17},
      {name: "Федя", age: 23},
      {name: "Клава", age: 22}
    ];
    function calcAvgAge(array) {
        let initialValue = 0;
        array.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
            console.log(accumulator.age + currentValue.age);
        }, initialValue)
    }
     calcAvgAge(data)
```

Comment: Return забыли в функции reduce

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Это на случай, если вас бесит постоянно писать `return` везде)

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'Саша', age: 19},
  {name: 'Катя', age: 21},
  {name: 'Миша', age: 17},
  {name: 'Федя', age: 23},
  {name: 'Клава', age: 22},
];

let calcAvgAge = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, obj) => acc + obj.age, 0);

console.log(calcAvgAge(data));
```

Comment: `(acc, obj) => acc + obj.age`

Comment: `Avg` в названии функции не смущает?

Comment: @Igor угу, верно, Intellisense мой подставил `+=` из-за скобок вокруг `acc + obj.age`.

Comment: @Qwertiy я название функции не трогал, мало ли, оно где еще у автора используется.

Comment: @Igor а нет, это я `=` вручную вкорячил... Это сейчас Intellisense мне его теперь предлагает прописывать.

Comment: @Pilaton, тем не менее, среднее считается немного не так.

Comment: @Qwertiy судя по заголовку вопроса и по примеру автора, речи о вычислении среднего возраста персонажей не стояло. Название функции могло остаться от какой-то другой задачки.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такое решение

```
  function calcAvgAge(array) {
   let initialValue = 0;

   return array.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
    accumulator += currentValue.age;

    return accumulator;
   }, initialValue);
  }
```

Comment: Бррррр... К тому же, всё равно не поможет.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]